# Github for Windows Error: could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable (-1). DLL rebasing may be required

Tags: windows, git, github, mingw

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: непонятно из-за чего git из GitHub for Windows перестал работать и постоянно выдаёт ошибку: `Error: could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable (-1). DLL rebasing may be required. See 'rebaseall / rebase --help'.`

Сколько искал решение в интернетах, так его и не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Идём по пути `C:\Users\<имя_пользователя>\AppData\Local\GitHub`
2. Открываем папку, название которой начинается с `PortableGit`
3. Открываем bat файл с названием `post-install.bat`
4. Enjoy!

Comment: В указанном пути отсутствует папка PortableGit и нет файла post-install.bat

Comment: @АсланУрдиев хм, возможно у Вас установлен Github Desktop работающий под Electron-ом, как следствие - переустановка приложения решит проблему, указанный способ применим лишь к более старым версиям клиента.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Turn off exploit protection field]

Выключить эти 2 поля (Выключены по умолчанию) в панели управления защита от эсплоитов и перезагрузить компьютер.

Comment: Увы, эта проблема возникла на Windows Server 2016, на котором попросту отключён Windows Defender и все связанные с ним функции. Проблема была вызвана повреждением файлов Git. Спасибо вам за желание помочь!